# windows embedded CE device to linux

Tags: linux, arm, windows-ce

I have a Windows embedded CE 6.0 device (with touchscreen and OTG, SDHC, RS232, USB, network Port). His processor type is: Freescale, ARM1136_Mx31.
Does anyone if it is possible to install linux in order to get a Linux device ?
Any tutorial to do that?
Is there in the market any similar device with Linux? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [ctake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13154/ctacke) notes, there can be external hardware and boot loader issues.  Additionally, certain *iMX* processors use a *secure boot* and it is difficult/impossible to add non-authorized code; according to *Chapter 7* of the iMX31 manual, it support HAB/RTIC and it may be difficult/impossible to load un-authorized software on this device, if the vendor has blown the fuses correctly; I would guess this is the case and even with a lot of effort you still can not load another OS unless you can [Jail break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) the device.

For this processor ([*iMX31*](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX31)), there is a Linux configuration.  Also, the peripherals noted, OTG, SDHC, RS232, USB, and network Port, are in the SOC silicon.  Ie, they are built right in the *iMX31* chip.  So these drivers are standard in Linux.

There maybe some GPIO pin that sets an external UART transciever (3V to +/- 12V), etc that are custom for this board/machine; also the *IOMUX* configuration for this board maybe difficult.  This would be where the issue lies.  Also, the basic thing like getting the SDRAM running maybe complex and not handled by Linux (they are handled by the boot loader).  It is also possible that SDRAM is setup automatically by *fuses*.

If the device has a standard boot loader like [uboot](/questions/tagged/uboot), etc.  Then it will be extremely easy to get a functional Linux, but perhaps not with all the peripherals functioning.  This particular *iMX* does not have security features, so you should be able to open the device and probe/observe electrical connections.  However, due to the *secure boot* feature, it is not at all simple and may even be impossible.

Comment: For someone attempting this, a monitor/debugger/jtag of any sort under CE can probe things like the IOMUX configuration.  A straight dump of those registers can be a base for a Linux configuration.  The DDR controller has some static registers, but will probably have dynamic behavior.  If you can trap and execute on that region, you can get register values like usb sniffers for Windows, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It's not as simple as that.  You're in the "desktop" mindset, where the BIOS, all hardware and busses are pretty standard so you can take one OS and swap it with another pretty easily.

Embedded devices, especially ARM devices aren't so simple.  First, there's no BIOS, but instead a bootloader, which is the code that starts execution when power is applied to the processor.  The bootloader's job is to set up RAM, the processor, and things like that, and then jump to the start address of the OS.  It's unlikely that your current bootloader is going to jump to the right place for a Linux OS.  It might be configurable, but you've not given any indication what the bootloader is.

Embedded hardware often has memory-mapped peripherals, CPLDs and the like.  The addresses for those devices is not standardized, so you have to know where they are physically located in the memory map so you can configure the OS to properly use them.  They also may have interrupts that need to be serviced, and you'd have to know what to mask and when for those peripheral.  Very detailed specs are typically required for that knowledge.

The typical path is to ask the device OEM if they offer Linux for the same hardware.  Many do.  If they don't and you still want Linux, move to some other hardware that supports it.  There are plenty of boards and devices in the market that run Linux and support the peripherals you've listed.  You need to determine the fit and form-factor you want.  A search engine should find at least a dozen pretty easily.